# Checking a function's expansion against a string

Tags: expansion, expl3, strings

I have a function `\Foo` that I test against what I think it should expand to for given arguments. Two problems:  1/ I can't 'log' the fully expanded version of `\Foo{arg}`. 2/ even when the expansion seems right by looking at the pdf output, tests based on `\str_if_eq:p` fail.

Here is an excerpt of the log file corresponding to Hook 1 in the code:

> \l_tmpa_tl=\Foo {A,B,C}.

I expected on the RHS of `=` an expanded version thereof. Why is it not, and can it be done?

Here's the output corresponding to Hook 2 in the code:

[image]

FAIL is the result of testing for the equality of the expansion `\Foo {A,B,C}`, shown on the LHS of the middle `+`, against the RHS. Where does the disagreement come from?

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \foo_str_compare:nn
{
  \exp_args:NNx \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \tl_log:N \l_tmpa_tl % Hook 1
  \exp_last_unbraced:Nf % Hook 2
  \str_if_eq:nnTF
  {
    {\l_tmpa_tl}
    {#2}
    {PASS}
    {FAIL+#1+#2+}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}
{m}
{
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \foo_seq {#1}
  \seq_use:Nnnn \foo_seq{,~}{,~}{~and~}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{}
{
  \foo_str_compare:nn{\Foo{A,B,C}}{A,~B~and~C}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither `\Foo` nor `\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn` is expandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only carry out a string comparison for expandable material. You have a document command, `\Foo`, which is protected, and also use `\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn`, which is non-expandable. (In `interface3`, any function not marked with a star is not expandable; broadly, anything which carries out an assignment or typesetting will no be expandable.)

Re-writing to use an expandable mapping for the comma list leads to

```latex
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \foo_str_compare:nn #1#2
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1} {#2}
      { PASS }
      { FAIL+#1+#2+}
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\Foo}
{m}
{
  \int_case:nnF { \clist_count:n {#1} }
    {
      { 0 } { }
      { 1 } {#1}
      { 2 } { \__foo_two:w #1 \s_stop }
    }
    { \__foo_list:w #1 \s_stop }
}
\cs_new:Npn \__foo_two:w #1 , #2 \s_stop { #1 ~ and ~ #2 }
\cs_new:Npn \__foo_list:w #1 , #2 \s_stop
  {
    #1 , ~
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \clist_count:n {#2} } > 2
      { \__foo_list:w #2 \s_stop }
      { \__foo_two:w #2 \s_stop }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{}
{
  \foo_str_compare:nn{\Foo{A,B,C}}{A,~B~and~C}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Test

\end{document}
```

As noted in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534098/73), you have various constructs in your code that are not the recommended pattern, and which I've avoided.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. This recursive algorithm is good to see for learning purposes. Maybe more practically, in case @Erwann didn't know, `expl3` already provides easy-to-use functions to do this boring work of enumerating list items that automatically  handle the special cases depending on the number of items: `\clist_use:Nnnn ` and `\seq_use:Nnnn`.

Comment: @frougon Yes, but currently not `\clist_use:nnnn`, which is what would be needed to stay expandable here

Comment: Well, I was only thinking about the typesetting aspect; but still, both of the functions I mentioned above are marked as being fully expandable, aren't they?

Comment: @frougon Yes, they are, but the user function here takes an `n`-type clist, so there would be a `set` step to use them

Comment: Ah, okay, this makes sense, thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't be able to extend this code to making `\clist_use:nnnn` because `\cs_new:Npn \__foo_two:w ...` is an assignment. Oh, well. Very useful regardless.

Comment: @Erwann No, the assignments are needed to create a mapping function, in the same way they are to define `\clist_use:Nnnn` or whatever. That's not the same as carrying out an assignment _at point of use_.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to extend this setup to `\Foo{clist}{sep1}{sep2}{sep3}` and expect that it would be testable with `\foo_str_compare:nn`, as that would entail setting `\__foo_two:w ...`, `\__foo_last_two:w` and `\__foo_list:w` locally (inside `Foo`'s body), because that would violate the condition for `\foo_str_compare:nn` to work, that its input be fully expandable. Are we saying the same thing?

Comment: @Erwann I've not coded up a full `\clist_use:nnnn` but that's quite doable it it's what you want. However, I'm not clear on why you want to make a comparison like this: people write lists in all sorts of ways, and I suspect you might miss 'real' hits.

Comment: I tested my understanding of the issue here: https://pastebin.com/aXZkbZU3 What I wanted was (in retrospect) to check a non-expandable function's evaluation (`\Foo{A, B, C})` against a string (`A,~B,~and~C`). I  retain that the takeaway is: it can't be done.

Answer (score 4):

You're using a nonexpandable function where expandability is necessary to succeed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \foo_str_compare:nn
 {
  \tl_log:e { #1 }
  \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1} {#2}
   {PASS}
   {FAIL+#1+#2+}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_log:n { e }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \foo_str_compare:nn{\seq_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_seq{,~}{,~}{~and~}}{A,~B~and~C}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Test{A,B,C}

\end{document}
```

Besides, you're abusing `\exp_args:...` and `\exp_last_unbraced:...`; for instance,

```
\exp_args:NNx \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
```

is better written as

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
```

and note also `\str_if_eq:eeTF`, to get full expansion.

You'll get “PASS” and, in the log file,

```
> A, B and C.
```

due to forced expansion with `\tl_log:e`.